# Firebase setPersistenceEnabled .causes massive memory use

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am encountering a strange problem.

I noticed my firebase Android app was becoming a bit sluggish, so decided to profile it. To my alarm within a few minutes the memory usage had grown to 500MB. I paused the profiler to see what was going on, all the calls were coming from com.google.android.gms, when I looked at the CPU usage it was showing high use for the firebase database.

I tracked the problem down to the call 'setPersistenceEnabled(true);' on my database instance, if I turn this off **performance returns and the RAM use is significantly lower.**

- When I start the app up I have a network connection, the RAM usage gets to 500MB within a few minutes
- When I start the app up I have **NO** network connection, the RAM usage gets to 500MB within a few minutes as well.
- I am not writing any data on startup, just reading some data from a particular node.
- If I comment out all calls to the firebase database, and just leave stubs the RAM usage appears **fine**
- If I reenable any one method that does any sort of database interaction, the RAM usage gets to 500MB within a few minutes

I almost think something has gone terribly wrong internally, and I should nuke the app and start again...

The Doc says

> When you enable disk persistence, your app writes the data locally to
>   the device so your app can maintain state while offline, even if the
>   user or operating system restarts the app.

And also

> By enabling persistence, any data that the Firebase Realtime Database
>   client would sync while online persists to disk and is available
>   offline, even when the user or operating system restarts the app. This
>   means your app works as it would online by using the local data stored
>   in the cache. Listener callbacks will continue to fire for local
>   updates.
>
> The Firebase Realtime Database client automatically keeps a queue of
>   all write operations that are performed while your app is offline.
>   When persistence is enabled, this queue is also persisted to disk so
>   all of your writes are available when the user or operating system
>   restarts the app. When the app regains connectivity, all of the
>   operations are sent to the Firebase Realtime Database server.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You're describing two different symptoms.  One is extra memory use, the other is execution speed.  If your app isn't running out of memory, then there really isn't a problem that can be diagnosed.  You have to trust that everything is operating within allowable bounds.  Execution speed is a different matter.  If you're able to track down *what* is actually being slow, that would be actionable information.

Comment: You are totally right - but they are related, there are lots of messages like this:  

`W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 86 bytes, free space 8 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes` . 
  
`Background concurrent copying GC freed 507266(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 56MB/80MB, paused 47us total 584.712ms` . 

I believe the performance hit is incurred by huge GC pausing the app while it cleans up after itself.

Comment: Wow just paid attention to it, occurs also in iOS. My app's memory usage spikes from 50MB to 250MB just by enabling this feature. I wonder if they know about it.